# Getting Simple Fields value in loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried everything. I'm using Simple Fields, no problem in getting the values in single post pages like single.php but nothing seems to work in the loop. I need to get the field value with slug $valutazione0 for every post in the loop. Below are the codes I tried. Of course I have already looked thoroughly the support website http://simple-fields.com/documentation/api/getting-values/simple_fields_values/

```
$postID = $post->ID;
$valutazione = simple_fields_values("valutazione0"[,$postID]);
```

or

```
$postID = $post->ID;
$valutazione = simple_fields_values($postID, "valutazione0");
```

or

```
$postID = $post->ID;
$valutazione = simple_fields_value($postID, "valutazione0");
```

or

```
$valutazione = simple_fields_values("$valutazione0"[,the_ID()]);
```

or

```
$valutazione = simple_fields_values("$valutazione0"[,<?php the_ID(); ?>]);
```

or

```
$valutazione = simple_fields_values("$valutazione0");
```

or

```
$valutazione0 = simple_fields_get_post_value(get_the_id(), array(3, 1), true);
```

This last one is the one I have always used in single post pages and there it works no problem.
Please help, Thanks in advance, Matt

Answer (score 0):

I always do something like:

```
        $args = array(
            'post_type'     =>  'post' //post type by default
        );
        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                $my_query->the_post();
                $identificador = $my_query->post->ID;
                $nombre = $my_query->post->post_title;
            } // end while
        } // end if
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

Hope that help you

Comment: mm I don't quite get it, can you make an example retrieving field with slug $valutazione0 ?